# Discord_Components allow multiple button responses

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am having a problem with Discord Components using the button functions.

The buttons appear as I'd like, however if I post more than one question with a button only one user gets a candy. The other's are given a message of 'this response has already been provided' or something along those lines.

Is there a way I can ask the same question multiple times and get a response from each user? It doesn't matter if its the same user, I just want to get 3 responses for 3 questions.

Example, I am giving away 3 candies. First 3 users to click the candy they want gets the candy they choose. However once one user clicks their candy, the other messages don't seem to take a response any longer.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Code below. It is called by a !givecandy command in my discord.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Would you like some candy?", colour=discord.Colour(0xffff00),
                                  description="Only one user may claim this candy!\n\nWhat kind of candy would you like?")
            botQuestion = await ctx.channel.send(
                embed=embed,
                components=[
                    [
                        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Laffy Taffy"),
                        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Lollipop"),
                        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Bubblegum"),
                        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Other")
                    ],
                ],
            )

            def check(res):
                return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel

            try:
                res = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
            except:
                await ctx.channel.send("Something went wrong, cancelling...", delete_after=10)
                await botQuestion.delete()
                return

            if res.component.label == "Other":
                await botQuestion.delete()
                embed = discord.Embed("Would you like some candy?", colour=discord.Colour(0xffff00),
                                  description="Only one user may claim this candy!\n\nWhat kind of candy would you like?")
                botQuestion = await ctx.channel.send(
                    embed=embed,
                    components=[
                        [
                            Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Twizzlers"),
                            Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Sour Patch Kids"),
                            Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="M & M's"),
                            Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Apple Slices")
                        ],
                    ],
                )

                try:
                    res = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
                except:
                    await ctx.channel.send("Something went wrong, cancelling...", delete_after=10)
                    await botQuestion.delete()
                    return

        candyRequested = res.component.label
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await botQuestion.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, so what I was missing was checking the message ID of the response also.

This now works as I needed it to.

Using...
`messageID = ctx.channel.last_message_id`

and including...
`res.message.id == messageID`

into my check, got it to work.